# Diferença entre comandos para interromper execução

Tags: python, controle-de-fluxo

Verifiquei que existem diversas formas de se interromper uma execução.

Basicamente qual é a diferença entre usar os comandos:

- break;
- sys.exit() ( Do módulo **sys**);
- os._exit() ( Do módulo **os**);
- exit();
- quit();

Reparei que alguns são vinculados a execução de uma rotina (`sys.exit()` como exemplo), e outros ao *kernel* (`exit()` entre outros ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `break`

Sai apenas de um laço e não termina a aplicação, ele é menos que um `return`. Até um `return` pode encerrar a aplicação quando ele está na mesma função que é ponto de entrada.

> `sys.exit()` ( Do módulo `sys`);

Encerra a aplicação lançando uma exceção ([`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)) que pode ser tratada em algum ponto, e todo processo de encerramento, incluindo liberação de recursos é executada antes de terminar. Considera-se que seu uso não é ideal e só deve ser chamado em casos muito específicos onde você entende bem o que está fazendo e precisa exatamente dessa solução de término imediato. Particularmente não acho tão ruim assim se realmente não tem mais nada para realizar, pelo menos em arquiteturas bem feitas que não tem dependência de um encerramento específico. Use-a preferencialmente.

> `os._exit()` (Do módulo `os`);

Encerra a execução imediatamente sem dar chance de executar mais nada, nem mesmo a liberação de recursos.

> `exit()`

O mesmo que a `sys.exit()`, mas considera-se que não deve ser usado. Não sei bem o motivo, mas acredito que funções que não pertencem a módulos se tornam ambíguas. Use em códigos muitos simples ou no REPL quando importar um módulo pode ser pior. Esse é o problema da linguagem que começa para ser de *script* e depois muda para ser mais que isso.

> `quit()`

Apenas um apelido para a função anterior. Clara violação do "só ter uma forma de realizar algo".

Não existe nada *kernel* aí, apenas que a `os.exit()` é uma chamada de encerramento que provavelmente pede ao OS para encerrar sem mais cerimônia. Não há vinculação à rotina alguma. Isso parece ser um entendimento errado. É uma função como outra qualquer que você chama em algum ponto do código e ela executa algo, no caso esse algo é o encerramento da aplicação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obs.: as funções `exit()` e `quit()` são definidas no módulo `site`, que é importado ao contexto automaticamente pelo interpretador, exceto se utilizado a flag `-S` ao executar o código. Com a flag, as funções não estarão definidas, por isso não é muito indicado depender delas.

Comment: ótima resposta, obrigado!  No meu caso por exemplo, o ideal então é utilizar o (sys.exit()),  pois pretendo utilizar em situações em que não é necessário executar mais nada posteriormente. Realmente muitas opções acaba confundindo rs

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, só existem 3 jeitos de terminar a aplicação:

1. *Normalmente*, ou seja, o código rodar até o final do script principal;
2. Ocorrer uma **exceção** que não seja tratada com `try`/`except`, causando uma mensagem de erro (*traceback*);
3. `os.exit_()`.

Os outros métodos que você passou não terminam o programa definitivamente - eles somente retornam de funções (`return`), saem de loops (`break`) ou sobem uma **exceção** `SystemExit` (demais métodos). O programa só vai terminar se isso fizer com que o código caia em uma das 3 situações citadas acima.

A exceção `SystemExit` faz o mesmo que qualquer outra exceção: As funcões e escopos são terminados e o fluxo de código vai voltando na pilha de chamadas até que a exceção seja tratada com o `try`/`except` ou volte para o escopo principal, onde, se até lá não foi tratada, causará a finalização do programa. A única diferença é que uma mensagem do tipo *traceback* não é impressa quando a exceção é a `SystemExit`.